# Basic IndexOutOfBoundsException for beginners

Tags: java, oop, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a Engineer class. And I'm creating a empty arraylist which is engineer type.

I'm creating a method to check arraylist, if arraylist isn't null it has to give me index 0. But if arraylist is null. My method has to create a new Engineer object and add to empty arraylist. After that adding, I'm  expecting  my method to give me index 0. But it throws IndexOutOfBoundsException. I know I missed some simple things, but I couldn't figure out how to fix.

```
ArrayList<Engineer>  newEmptyEngineerList = new ArrayList<>();
findLastEngineer(newEmptyEngineerList);

public static void findLastEngineer(ArrayList aa){

    if (aa.get(0)!=null){
        System.out.println(aa.get(0));
    }
    else {
        Engineer eng = new Engineer();           
        aa.add(0,eng);
        System.out.println(aa.get(0));
    }

}
```

Comment: A `null` array list and an empty array list are not the same thing. It is possible to have an empty, non-null array list, which will crash your code.

Comment: To amend Silvios comment: a `null` Arraylist is different from an empty ArrayList (having size() == 0) and both are different from an ArrayList having it least one element where the first element is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that the list is not empty before calling `get(0)` on it.
Also avoid using raw array list and prefer interface `List` to its implementation when using as function parameters or return type.

```java
public static void findLastEngineer(List<Engineer> aa) {
    if (aa.isEmpty()){
        aa.add(new Engineer());
    }
    // get and print last element
    System.out.println(aa.get(aa.size() - 1));
}
```